# Yii - image files don't display

Tags: php, yii

I have img tag in my view file like the below.

```
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/img/test.jpg'; ?>" />
```

But, it doesn't show the image.

I have "img" folder on the same directory where `index.php`(front controller)exists.

What's wrong!?

Anybody knows how to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance!!!

***+++Added 1+++***

I'm developing in local environment.

***+++Added 2+++***

Very weird thing is happening.

When I access the one specific image by typing the path to the image on browser, the requested image  is displayed.

```
http://localhostname/img/sidebar.gif
```

But when I access the other images in the same img foloder, I get "Forbidden" error.

Also, when I type the below in my view, it shows the image.

```
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/img/sidebar.jpg'; ?>" />
```

But, when I type the path to the other images that exists in the same img directory, it doesn't show any images.

Comment: Go to a page that should have an image. Then look at the html source code, see what url is being generated for the image. Should help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

This is the value for src attribute when I use Yii::app()->baseUrl
img/see.jpg

And this is the value for src attribute I get when I use Yii::app()->betBaseUrl(true).
http://localhostname/img/see.jpg

By the way, I'm developing my application in local environment.

Comment: I added more infomation describing my situation. I appreciate it if you take a look at it and give me any advice if possible :)

Comment: What does your .htaccess file look like?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I haven't created .htaccess file yet.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Yii::app()->baseUrl`

Try this: `Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true)`

By default, baseUrl returns relative URL.

```
<img src="<?= Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true) ?>/img/sidebar.jpg" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!
I tried your advice but, it didn't work :(

Comment: it returned the absolute path though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added more infomation describing my situation. I appreciate it if you take a look at it and give me any advice if possible :)

Answer (score 1):

If images not show, the debug browser have error 404. See there. You will see full url that should get. It url not the one you expect - `"<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/img/test.jpg'; ?>"`. You should edit you code in conformity with this error.